# Write using mouse on R plot?

Tags: r, scatter

I created scattergram using the `plot()` function in R.

Is there any possibility to draw on this graph?

I would like to add a straight line and get parameters of it, but in my opinion `abline()` can be inconvenient (I would like to draw many lines and choose one which will be most proper).

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: I made a few edits for clarity, but I'm still not getting this: do you want to draw lines manually (via the mouse) and then determine their parameters?  What are you finding inconvenient about `abline()`?  One GUI method may be to add two sliders: one for an intercept and one for the slope.  In RStudio, the `manipulate` package and function may be the answer.

Comment: Can you clarify why you would like to add lines?  It could be the case that there's a better way to get the lines that interest you, e.g. confidence bands.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at RStudio and this example:

```
library(manipulate)
data = matrix(rnorm(20), ncol = 2)

example <- function(data, a, b){
  plot(data[,1],data[,2])
  abline(a = a, b = b)
}

manipulate(
  example(data, a, b),
  a = slider(-5,5),
  b = slider(-5,5)
)
```

This will put a new line on the plot, and allow you to tweak its slope and intercept.

This was inspired by the example on this page: http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/106-rstudio-manipulate-command

Note that this requires installing RStudio (it ships with the `manipulate` package, I believe).  For more info, [see the site](http://rstudio.org/).

Others' solutions with `locator` can be done in base R.

Comment: You should probably point out that this requires some packages to be loaded

Answer (score 7):

Use `locator()`, a function that allows you to get the coordinates of the mouse pointer when clicking on a plot. Then use

```
plot(cars)
xy <- locator(n=2)
lines(xy, col="red", lwd=5)
lm(y~x, xy)
abline(coef(lm(y~x, xy)))
coef(lm(y~x, xy))
(Intercept)           x 
  33.142094    1.529687
```

Of course the correct way of fitting lines through data is to use a proper model.  Here is how you can do it with `lm`:

```
abline(coef(lm(dist~speed, cars)), col="blue")
```

I made the following graph with this code:

- The thick red line is the line connecting my two mouse clicks
- The black line is the `abline` through these points
- The blue line is the line of best fit produced by `lm`

[image]

**Warning 1:** `locator` only works on some graphics devices.  See `?locator` for more details.

**Warning 2:**  Drawing lines of fit by hand could well be a really stupid idea.  Use a regression function like `lm` or a smoothing function like `loess` instead.

Comment: Andrie is correct about using such lines for fitting.  However, they can be useful for showing bounds, albeit not very good for confidence intervals.  Which raises the question: what is the point of adding the lines?

Comment: @Iterator: The lines are probably useless for stats purposes, but you could make a nice dot-to-dot puzzle.

Comment: @Richie: Look for my next package `paintByNumbeRs`.  :)  Hmm, might be good for image tagging.

Comment: @Iterator and @RichieCotton I have edited my answer to reflect a) how to extract the end points from `locator`, and b) how to draw the *proper* line of best fit.

Answer (score 4):

If you were hoping to add horizontal or vertical lines to your plot interactively, you may want to use the `locator()` function to capture the position of a mouse click on the plot.

For example, the following code would allow the repeated addition of vertical lines to an existing plot:

```
repeat {
  click.loc <- locator(1)
  if(!is.null(click.loc)) abline(v=click.loc$x)
  else break
}
```

You could adapt this for horizontal lines with `abline(h=click.loc$y)`